# php re calculate numeric values of css string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to recalculate `INT` values of a `CSS` string.
 
PHP string:

```
$str = "background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute; left:522px; top:422px; width:155px; height:178px;";
```

Then i examine each value

```
$strArr= explode(";", $str);
// output:
Array
(
        [0] => background-repeat:no-repeat
        [1] =>  position:absolute
        [2] =>  left:522px
        [3] =>  top:422px
        [4] =>  width:155px
        [5] =>  height:178px
        [6] =>
)
```

From here I would like to run a process and change `INT`values that have `PX`.  So this would affect items `[2], [3], [4], [5]`

my attempt

```
foreach ($strArr as $piece) {

  $item = preg_match("/\d/", $piece); // check if contains `INT`
  if($ss==1){
      // run a process here to change int values
  }

}
// reconstruct string
// ex: $newStr = "background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute; left:261px; top:211px; width:78px; height:89px;";
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There are some answers that will help with the regex part. Keep in mind PHP has functions like `preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback`, which may be particularly interesting for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: replacement is not the way to go.  im looking to pull `int` values, run a sub routine, then create new string.

Comment: Based on your question and the answer you accepted, `preg_replace_callback` seems to be to be exactly what you want, but perhaps I misunderstand.

Comment: my fault, i thought it would be implemented slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$str = "background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute; left:522px; top:422px; width:155px; height:178px;";
$strArr= explode(";", $str);
foreach ($strArr as $piece) {

  $item = preg_match('/[0-9]+px/', $piece); // check if contains int followed by px
  if($item==1){
      $piece = preg_replace('/[0-9]+px/', '400px',$piece);
  }//here I'm replacing all the INT values to 400px
$myValue[]=$piece;
}
$formattedStr = implode($myValue,';');
echo $formattedStr; //the result string with all the px values changed to 400
```

Comment: lets say i was examing this `left:522px`, regex would give me the `int val`, but then how would i reconstruct the new value with `left:`.  in other words i need to hold on to the original property.

Comment: im not understanding,  im not replacing string anywhere

Comment: you want to recalculate and replace the value in left:522px with values like left:400px right?

Comment: the left value is already in there you're not doing anything to it all you're doing is check if a string has INT followed by px like top:92px the you're saying just replace the int and px part of the string like top:10px. I've edited the ans again for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

You will match more precisely using the regex `/(?<=:)\d+(?=px)/g` , This will get you only the numeric part, You can then do the calculation.

Updated, try this.

```
<?php
$str = "background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute; test:0px; left:522px; top:422px; width:155px; height:178px;";
$strArr= explode(";", $str);
foreach ($strArr as $pieces => $piece) {
    $item = preg_match("/(?<=:)\d+(?=px)/", $piece, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    if ($match) {
        $intval = (int)$match[0][0];
        $offset = $match[0][1];
        $newVal = $intval + 100; // your calculation here
        $strArr[$pieces] = substr($piece, 0, $offset) . $newVal . 'px';
    }
}
```

Comment: would you know the regex to grab everything left of the colon `left:522px`  (i would need `left`) so that i can re create the string after int has been changed?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute; left:522px; top:422px; width:155px; height:178px;";

// this regex pattern will take any number that ends with px, i.e. 500px, 1px, 20px
preg_match_all('/([0-9+])+px/', $str, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
  $intvalue = (int) $match;
  $str = str_replace($match, '500px', $str); // subsitute 500px for what it should be replaced with
}

// $str is now updated..
```

Comment: thank you,  but how can i calculate `500px`?  i would need only the numeric portion on each of these items

Comment: updated, $intvalue would be the number without the "px" string